# Is there a name for a function that satisfies $f(f(x)) = x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have tried to look up for a function class that satisfies $f(f(x)) = x$. I wonder if there is a dedicated name to that property.

Comment: Such a function is sometimes called an [involution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Involution).

Comment: Could be an involution (a function that is the inverse of itself) or a "do nothing" function, that doesn't change the input at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function $f:X \to X$ such that $f\circ f = \operatorname{id}_X$ is called an [**involution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)), or **self-inverse** (since such a function is its own inverse).